# Python3 custom view objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to implement custom view objects in Python 3?

According to the documentation:

> The objects returned by dict.keys(), dict.values() and dict.items() are view objects. They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes.

So is it possible to somehow create custom view objects?

I was searching very long any information about it, but the only explanations I found are **what** are the views, not how to **create custom** or **how they are implemented** (their internal mechanism).

Comment: could you subclass dictionary and leverage the views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, those functions return a list.  In Python 3, you get objects that act like a list.  What does it take to act like a list?

There are [a number of 'special functions'](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) you can use to change an object's behavior.  You're probably familiar with `__init__()` already.  For making a 'view', the most important are probably `__len__()`, `__getitem__()` and maybe `__iter__()`.

Comment: Ah so a view is nothing special? It is simple a iterable class that has combined other methods?

Comment: @danilo2 A view doesn't *need* to be anything special.  I suspect that it's probably implemented in C for performance purposes.

Comment: The idea that views "act like lists" is a bit extreme. For one thing, they can behave like sets. For example, membership tests (`… in d.keys()`) are way faster than with lists. Also, one cannot append to views, etc.