# What is the Pythonic equivalent of const-references?

Tags: python, python-3.x, const-correctness, information-hiding

There has been a lot of debate (at least on SO) about lack of `const`-correctness and lack of true `private` members in Python. I am trying to get used to the Pythonic way of thinking.

Suppose I want to implement a fuel tank.  It has a capacity, it can be refilled, or fuel can be consumed out of it.  So I would implement it as follows:

```
class FuelTank:

    def __init__(self, capacity):

        if capacity < 0:
            raise ValueError("Negative capacity")
        self._capacity = capacity

        self._level = 0.0

    @property
    def capacity(self):
        return self._capacity

    @property
    def level(self):
        return self._level

    def consume(self, amount):

        if amount > self.level:
            raise ValueError("amount higher than tank level")

        self._level -= amount


    def refill(self, amount):

        if amount + self.level > self.capacity:
            raise ValueError("overfilling the tank")

        self._level += amount
```

So far I've put some level of `const`-correctness in my code:  by not implementing a property setter for `capacity` I inform the client that `capacity` cannot be changed after the object is constructed. (Though technically this is always possible by accessing `_capacity` directly.)  Similarly, I tell the client that you can read the `level` but please use `consume` or `refill` methods to change it.

Now, I implement a `Car` that has a `FuelTank`:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, consumption):
        self._consumption = consumption
        self._tank = FuelTank(60.0)


    @property
    def consumption(self):
        return self._consumption

    def run(self, kms):

        required_fuel = kms * self._consumption / 100

        if required_fuel > self._tank.level:
            raise ValueError("Insufficient fuel to drive %f kilometers" %
                             kms)

        self._tank.consume(required_fuel)

    def refill_tank(self, amount):

        self._tank.refill(amount)
```

Again I'm implying that client is not supposed to access `_tank` directly.  The only think (s)he can do is to `refill_tank`.

After some time, my client complains that (s)he needs a way to know how much fuel is left in the tank.  So, I decide to add a second method called `tank_level`

```
    def tank_level(self):
        return self._tank.level
```

Fearing that that a `tank_capacity` will become necessary soon, I start to add wrapper methods in `Car` to access all methods of `FuelTank` except for `consume`.  This is obviously not a scalable solution.  So, I can alternatively add the following `@property` to `Car`

```
    @property
    def tank(self):
        return self._tank
```

But now there is no way for the client to understand `consume` method should not be called.  In fact this implementation is only slightly safer than just making `tank` a public attribute:

```
    def __init__(self, consumption):
        self._consumption = consumption
        self.tank = FuelTank(60.0)
```

and saving extra lines of code.

So, in summary, I've got three options:

1. Writing a wrapper method in `Car` for every method of `FuelTank` that the client of `Car` is allowed to use (not scalable and hard to maintain).
2. Keeping `_tank` (nominally) private and allowing client to access it as a getter-only property.  This only protects me against an excessively 'idiot' client that may try to set `tank` to a completely different object.  But, otherwise is as good as making `tank` public.
3. Making `tank` public, and asking client "please do not call `Car.tank.consume`"

I was wondering which option is considered as the best practice in a Pythonic world?

Note in C++ I would've made `level` and `capacity` methods `const` in `Tank` class and declared `tank` as private member of `Car` with a `get_tank()` method that returns a `const`-reference to `tank`.  This way, I would only need one wrapper method for `refill`, and I give the client full access to any `const` members of `Tank` (with zero future maintenance cost).   As a matter of taste, I find this an important feature that Python lacks.

---

**Clarification.**

I understand that what can be achieved in C++ is almost certainly impossible to achieve in Python (due to their fundamental differences). What I am mainly trying to figure out is which one of the three alternatives is the most Pythonic one?  Does option (2) have any particular advantage over option (3)?  Is there a way to make option (1) scalable?

Comment: Not being overly familiar with C++, what does declaring as `const` do for making methods of objects inaccessible? In Python you may be interested in [view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary-view) for that kind of purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14652409/476.

Comment: @deceze Returning a const reference would prevent non-const methods (such as consuming fuel, resulting in a state change) from being directly invoked on the returned reference. It is a method of allowing only the "getter" methods (marked as const) to be invoked on a type that also has "setters".

Comment: return a copy of your internal value - not it itself? that way its readable but not writeable?#

Comment: @PatrickArtner That's a perfectly valid solution for small objects (like the one in this toy example).  But suppose (a smart) `FuelTank` stored the log of all `refill` events.  Then it would be very inefficient to copy all those logs on return (especially if the client is accessing it in that particular instant just to read the level).

Comment: It really sounds like View objects fit here, which in a nutshell is a class which accepts an instance of your `Tank` and only exposes some getters and perhaps other magic methods to act as a dict or such. This kind of thing can be implemented mostly through introspection and magic dunder methods without needing to expose properties manually one by one.

Comment: This might be a better question for our sister site [programmers.se] rather than Stack Overflow; the focus here is on specific, narrow problems with concrete answers; questions about what constitutes good practice, particularly where the focus is more on design than code, are much more welcome there. (See [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) describing how the scopes differ).

Comment: Why shouldn't the user be allowed to call `consume`? Running the car's engine isn't the only way to remove fuel from a tank; you can siphon gas out, for example. I think you are premature in deciding whether adding more methods to `Car` is scalable or not.

Comment: You can also use a leading underscore in front of properties if you intend them to be 'protected' or 'package' access. I think it's enough to add a note in the doc string indicating the scope a method is intended for. There's a lot of trust in Python, and people turn out to usually be smart enough to follow direction.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your suggestion. Is there a way to migrate the question to the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) automatically?  Or I should ask the same question there?

Comment: Migration requires a moderator's approval. One can flag the question for moderator attention and ask them to do it, or just close or delete it here and re-ask there. Since you already have an answer, flagging for moderator support is the better approach, since that will move the answer with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Python doesn’t have any standard way of *marking* a method `const`, there can’t be a *built-in* way of providing a value (*i.e.*, an object) that restricts access to them.  There are, however, two idioms that can be used to provide something similar, both made easier by Python’s dynamic attributes and reflection facilities.

If a class is to be designed to support this use case, you can **split** its interface: provide only the read interface on the “real” type, then provide a wrapper that provides the write interface and forwards any unknown calls to the reader:

```
class ReadFoo:
  def __init__(self): self._bar=1
  @property
  def bar(self): return self._bar
class Foo:
  def __init__(self): self._foo=ReadFoo()
  def read(self): return self._foo
  def more(self): self._foo._bar+=1
  def __getattr__(self,n): return getattr(self._foo,n)

class Big:
  def __init__(self): self._foo=Foo()
  @property
  def foo(self): return self._foo.read()
```

Note that `Foo` does not **inherit** from `ReadFoo`; another distinction between Python and C++ is that Python cannot express `Base &b=derived;`, so we have to use a separate object.  Neither can it be constructed from one: clients cannot then think they’re supposed to do so to obtain write access.

If the class isn’t designed for this, you can **reverse** the wrapping:

```
class ReadList:
  def __init__(self,l): self._list=l
  def __getattr__(self,n):
    if n in ("append","extend","pop",…):
      raise AttributeError("method would mutate: "+n)
    return getattr(self._list,n)
```

This is obviously more work since you must make a **complete** blacklist (or whitelist, though then it’s a bit harder to make helpful error messages).  If the class is cooperative, though, you could use this approach with **tags** (*e.g.*, a function attribute) to avoid the explicit list and having two classes.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer.  If my understanding is correct the second solution is actually what has been called a "view object" in one of the comments above, right?

Comment: @kMaster: It’s one way of implementing one, yes.